# Loop several times with different values each time

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, loops

I need to make a loop that goes through each time with different values for the rowno. Here is part of the code:

```
int rowno = 2;
File file = new File("path");
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
String value = workbook.getSheet(0).getCell(1, rowno).getContents();
```

The next row numbers would be 11, 20, 29 and so on...

Comment: create a set of rowno

Comment: Use a `for` loop? Increment by `9`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare array, list, or set with rows you need to check:

```
int[] rowsToCheck = { 11, 20, 29 };
```

And iterate over the array taking the values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowsToCheck.length; i++) {
    String value = workbook.getSheet(0).getCell(1, rowsToCheck[i]).getContents();
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
 if the numbers are consecutive 11 + 9 = 20 + 9 = 29 + 9.... as [Tarik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/990750/tarik) suggested, just make the counter of the loop increment by 9.

```
int numberOfRows = // what you neeed

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i+=9) {
    String value = workbook.getSheet(0).getCell(1, i).getContents();
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing something but the following code should do:

```
int rowno;
int lastrow=100; // Correct as needed
File file = new File("path");
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
for (rowno=2; rowno<lastrow; rowno+=9) {
    String value = workbook.getSheet(0).getCell(1, rowno).getContents();
}
```

Comment: as I understand, the point is the rows are not consecutive numbers... but if so your answer looks better ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the number of rows on each on the excel file. Once you have the sheet, you know the maximum number of rows, then just iterate and increment by 9.

```
Sheet currentSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(int index);

for (int rowno = 2; rowno < currentSheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows(); rowno = rowno + 9)
{
    String value = currentSheet.getCell(1, rowno).getContents();
}
```

Comment: I meant, that whoever downvoted you should explain. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: By the way "for (rowno;" should be "for (rowno=2;"?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 2; i < maxValue; i = i + 9) {

}
```

Comment: I am asking about who downvoted you. Your answer is correct.

Comment: It just pisses me off when people downvote with no explanation. I think an explanation should be required for downvotes.

Comment: actually seems to be right... but I can bet someone does not like code-only answers.... it happened to me formerly really often.... SO users.... xD